# How to get specific data from an array?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an array like this:

```
var records:Array = new Array();
records.push({name:"nh", medinc:"66303"});
records.push({name:"ct", medinc:"65958"});
records.push({name:"nj", medinc:"65173"});
records.push({name:"md", medinc:"64596"});
```

etc...

for all 50 states. I am wondering if I can get the "medinc" data by using the "name" value?
For instance, can I call the "nh" name value and get "66303" returned?

How can I do this?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object instead to store the records then you can get the medinc directly using the name:

```
var records:Object = {};

records["nh"] = { medinc:"66303"};
records["ct"] = { medinc:"65958"};
records["nj"] = { medinc:"65173"};
records["md"] = { medinc:"64596"};

trace(records["nh"]["medinc"]);
```